# Speeding up inner-joins and subqueries while restricting row size and table membership

Tags: sql, mysql, database, subquery, join

I'm developing an rss feed reader that uses a bayesian filter to filter out boring blog posts.

The Stream table is meant to act as a FIFO buffer from which the webapp will consume 'entries'. I use it to store the temporary relationship between entries, users and bayesian filter classifications.

After a user marks an entry as read, it will be added to the metadata table (so that a user isn't presented with material they have already read), and deleted from the stream table. Every three minutes, a background process will repopulate the Stream table with new entries (i.e. whenever the daemon adds new entries after the checks the rss feeds for updates).

Problem: The query I came up with is hella slow. More importantly, the Stream table only needs to hold one hundred unread entries at a time; it'll reduce duplication, make processing faster and give me some flexibility with how I display the entries.

The query (takes about 9 seconds on 3600 items with no indexes):

```
insert into stream (entry_id, user_id) 
select entries.id, subscriptions_users.user_id 
 from entries 
inner join subscriptions_users on subscriptions_users.subscription_id = entries.subscription_id 
where subscriptions_users.user_id = 1 
  and entries.id not in (select entry_id 
                           from metadata 
                          where metadata.user_id = 1) 
  and entries.id not in (select entry_id 
                          from stream where user_id = 1);
```

The query explained: insert into stream all of the entries from a user's subscription list (subscriptions_users) that the user has not read (i.e. do not exist in metadata) and which do not already exist in the stream.

Attempted solution: adding limit 100 to the end speeds up the query considerably, but upon repeated executions will keep on adding a different set of 100 entries that do not already exist in the table (with each successful query taking longer and longer).

This is close but not quite what I wanted to do.

Does anyone have any advice (nosql?) or know a more efficient way of composing the query?

Comment: MySQL. 

I wouldn't be opposed to leaving with sql that works on postgres tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO STREAM 
  (entry_id, user_id) 
   SELECT e.id, 
          su.user_id 
     FROM ENTRIES e
     JOIN SUBSCRIPTIONS_USERS su ON su.subscription_id = e.subscription_id 
                                AND su.user_id = 1 
LEFT JOIN METADATA md ON md.entry_id = e.id
                     AND md.user_id = 1
LEFT JOIN STREAM s ON s.entry_id = e.id
                  AND s.user_id = 1
    WHERE md.entry_id IS NULL
      AND s.entry_id IS NULL
```

In MySQL, the `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` is the most efficient means of getting data that exists in one table, but not another.  [Reference link](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Check the query performance before looking at indexes.

In Postgres:

- `NOT IN`
- `NOT EXISTS`
- `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`

...[are equivalent](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/).

Comment: Assuming the values Sequel Pro returns are accurate, on an empty stream table that insert takes less time (a total of 7seconds vs 12seconds) but on a filled table it takes longer (12seconds vs 8 seconds). 


I haven't had time to experiment with adding indexes - I would imagine it might improve; I'll report back later.


Also: any ideas on how to limit it to filling it with only 1 hundred items :D?

Comment: @hiffy: Try adding `LIMIT 100` to the end of the query.  Could the `METADATA` and `STREAM` entry_id columns allow null values?

Comment: @OMG, adding LIMIT 100 will add a different hundred entries everytime it's executed until the unread entries are exhausted; I wanted it to insert one hundred at most everytime it's executed — a kind of 'replenishing' of the stream table. 30 entries have been read? This time around insert the top 30 that match. As to the schema, entry_ids can never be null, if that is what you asking.

Comment: @hiffy: Use and `ORDER BY` clause to ensure consistency.

Comment: @OMG No dice. I added an `ORDER BY e.published DESC LIMIT 100` to the very end, and it keeps inserting a fresh one hundred entries (instead of the desired behaviour of 0 rows being affected, since no new rows were read). Am I misunderstanding something? It seems to be the only place I can syntactically place that restriction in the query. (Thanks so much for your help so far! I'd upvote you if I had the reputation).

Comment: @hiffy: To stop duplicates from being inserted, you need to specify a column as a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

> The query (takes about 9 seconds on
>   3600 items with no indexes):

Then I would try to start off with some indexes...

OR **LEFT JOIN NULL** (And Indexes)

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA A LEFT JOIN
    TABLEB B ON A.ID = B. ID
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Oh, of course, but I still want to restrict the table membership to a hundred per user (assuming that's a good idea at all), and while my SQL is rusty it *feels* like the query is very inefficient to begin with.

Comment: Yes. Sub selects *NOT IN* can be replaced with **left joins is null**. Also MySql LIMIT and MSSQL TOP restricts returned number of rows.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` is only faster on MySQL.  It's not as efficient as `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` on SQL Server, and all three are equivalent on Oracle & Postgres.

Comment: Not in is slower, but not exists can be as fast if used with an outside ref.

Answer (score 0):

One way to optimize the select is to replace the subqueries with joins.

Something like:

```
select entries.id, subscriptions_users.user_id
from entries 
inner join subscriptions_users on subscriptions_users.subscription_id = entries.subscription_id 
left join metadata  md on (user_id,entry_id)
left join stream  str on (user_id, entry_id) 
where subscriptions_users.user_id = 1 and where md.user_id is null and str.user_id is null;
```

You would have to make sure that the join conditions for the left join are correct. I am not sure what your exact schema is, so I can't.

Also, adding indexes would also help.